# Python data frame drop duplicate rows based on pairwise columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I remove the duplicate rows based on pairwise columns (Col1, Col2) and (Col3, Col4)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' :  ['A','A','C','A','C'],
                   'Col2' : ['B','B','D','B','D'],
                   'Col3' : ['C','A','C','B','D'],
                   'Col4' :['D','B','D','A','C']})


Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
 A        B      C       D
 A        B      A       B
 C        D      C       D
 A        B      B       A
 C        D      D       C
```

The desired output is:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
 A        B      C       D
 A        B      B       A
 C        D      D       C
```

row two and row three are dropped because

```
A B = A B and C D = C D
```

I tried something like

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[['Col1', 'Col2'],['Col3', 'Col4']])
```

but this is not right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try compare with `values`

```
out = df[np.all(df[['Col1', 'Col2']].values != df[['Col3', 'Col4']].values,1)]
Out[298]: 
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0    A    B    C    D
3    A    B    B    A
4    C    D    D    C
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try comparing columns like this.

```
new_df = df[(df['Col1'] != df['Col3']) & (df['Col2'] != df['Col4'])]
print(new_df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0    A    B    C    D
3    A    B    B    A
4    C    D    D    C
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following approach:

For the df ->

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' :  ['A','A','C','A','C'],
                   'Col2' : ['B','B','D','B','D'],
                   'Col3' : ['C','A','C','B','D'],
                   'Col4' :['D','B','D','A','C']})
```

Comparing the values of `(Col1,Col2)` with `(Col3,Col4)` and drop the duplicates

```
desired_output = df[df[['Col1', 'Col2']].values != df[['Col3', 'Col4']].values].drop_duplicates()
desired_output
```

Output:

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
0    A       B       C        D
3    A       B       B        A
4    C       D       D        C
```